# PHP MYSQL Access all columns in the same field using an array using FOR loop

Tags: php, mysql

Clear and direct question here. I have a FOR loop which I am using to access data in an array. As you probably know if more than 1 column exists in the same field, the last one takes precedence. How does one access all the data in the columns with the same field? 
here is my for loop

```
for($counter=0;$counter<$found;$counter++)
```

{

```
$cellphonenumber=$details['Cellphone_Number'];
$childname=$details['Child_First_Name'];
    $parentname=$details['First_Name'];
$msg="Dear $parentname, your child $childname is due for shots";
```

I have hundreds of records and i need to access each one of them and send the msg. Currently using mysql_fetch_assoc. I heard you can use the numeric index of the columns. how do you do that?

Comment: Are you saying there are multiple columns in your database with the same name? Why? Do you have the authority to change that?

Comment: I have many records in the same column

Comment: What do you mean you have many records in the same column? Maybe you should start showing us some of your data... what does the content of one row look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but the code should probably look something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT Email, Cellphone_Number, Child_First_name, First_Name FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $cellphonenumber = $row['Cellphone_Number'];
    $childname = $row['Child_First_Name'];
    $parentname = $row['First_Name'];

    $msg="Dear $parentname, your child $childname is due for shots";

    mail($row['Email'], "Important Subject", $msg, "From: me@example.com");

}
```

Comment: Yours works a bit. But it picks only the first row. I have hundreds of rows. How can I pick the rest?

Comment: This picks every row from the table, not just one.

Comment: somtimes `mail()` takes awhile to send, the script may be timing out while waiting to complete sending some of the emails

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. I had done a silly thing before the while loop. i had another array under the same curly braces. For some reason that affected the while loop. I dont know why. Once I removed it, it worked beautifully. Thanks Again.